# Cloning process failing

Tags: windows-xp, clone, windows-xp-embedded

I am a brand spankin new software and tech intern at an industrial company that uses antiquated technology. My second day and I am tasked with troubleshooting the failure of a cloning process.

The application hosting the process is called SelfImage version 1.2.1 build 92. The operating system software is Windows XP Embedded standard. I am attempting to use the SelfImage software to TAKE a "system state image file" (i.e. not a selfie-type image file) LOADED FROM the Standmount Embedded Automation Controller/ UNO-2174AUNO 2174A running my system, and TARGETED TO a SQFlash Industrial Grade 8GB drive, also connected to the system (Removable Disk F:).

After SelfImage finishes its cloning process, I go to my F: drive and it either gives me an error of "Disk in F is not formatted", OR there are files in there but I assume they are corrupted, since these actions describe the files: rightClick>Properties>FileType:FILE.

VERY INTERESTING DETAIL:The occurrence of these two outcomes is determined by whether or not the card written to is EJECTED and then REINSERTED between the time it is written to and the time I navigate to the F: drive in Windows Explorer.

At this point I initiate a complete reformatting (i.e. a wipe) of the SQFlash and start the process again, but this time with trying to clone a different image.

Up until 3 weeks ago (long before I started here, so I cannot be blamed-PHEW!) this cloning process worked for my company, for these images.

To elaborate: My company has a permanent copy of the machine program that is loaded on to the UNO and then we try to clone that file onto a different, blank card. Also, the age of the permanent copy does make a difference as to whether the cloning process works. (i.e. Images from a card dedicated to newer machine programs are clonable, while images from cards dedicated to older machine system programs are not clonable.

Any ideas?

THINGS I HAVE TRIED:

- Changing the UNO unit
- Uninstalling and reinstalling SelfImage

Comment: Have you actually tried just restoring the files? Just because windows (I presume that's how you're reading them) can't read them, doesn't mean they're corrupt.

Comment: You might want to check if there are error logs generated during cloning, which may assist  you in diagnosing this issue.