# Dangers of resetting CMOS to "default settings"..? Can resetting BIOS/CMOS stuff have adverse effects on my XP system?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bios, reset

In troubleshooting a problem I am having, I found one possible solution. (If you are interested: It is No. 4 of this article https://www.raymond.cc/blog/help-a-disk-read-error-occurred-press-ctrlaltdelete-to-restart/ .)

The segment I am interested in reads like this:

- 4_Resetting / Updating the BIOS
- In rare circumstances setting the BIOS back to defaults can fix the
  issue. You can usually get to the BIOS by pressing Del or F2 etc
  during boot. There should be an option to reset to defaults.."

Alright, so. I wanna try this but...This is a company computer...Any one know if there are any risks for this course of action? Can resetting BIOS/CMOS stuff have adverse effects on my XP system?

If you want more information about why I would want to do this in the first place, please see my other post: [Cloning process failing](https://superuser.com/questions/1212438/cloning-process-failing)

Comment: *This is a company computer* - You should have your System Administrator fix the computer, if I was the SA at your company, and you attempted to reset the BIOS I would never allow you to use company hardware again.  DO NOT DO THIS.

Comment: Thank you for your concern..  I am an intern, so I am operating under the assumption of forgiveness. Leave concerns of what I am at liberty to try to me.. In the mean time, could you perhaps elaborate on WHY you met the idea of resetting the CMOS settings to default with such apprehension? I am trying to understand the effects of doing this...

Comment: You might want to elaborate on the problem you're having, because I'm going to go ahead and guess that resetting your BIOS won't fix it. I also agree with @Ramhound, it's not a good idea to do it anyway.

Comment: Because changing the configuration of company hardware, after it's been configured, means it has to be configured properly (again) by somebody.  *Of course systems I configure wouldn't even allow a intern to reset the BIOS firmware for that exact reason.*

Comment: This is the most basic of XP systems.. Can I have an example of a functionality that is determined by how the BIOS is configured?

Comment: @SarahSchnoor - Device boot order.  You can also boot a Windows installation off the network.  A firmware reset would result in this configuration being lost.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for this discussion! I believe I understand now. As you originally insisted, I will not take this action

Answer (score 1):

If a custom boot device or order is used resetting the BIOS could change the boot order, rendering the disk unusable until the order is reset.

It could disable an important device or enable an otherwise BIOS disabled device. It might turn off or erase a TPM holding your disk encryption keys rendering the system completely unusable and requiring it to be completely reformatted.

It could enable a disabled webcam on a laptop, creating a potential security concern if your company considers it such.

Resetting the BIOS should only be done as a last resort to make a system boot, and only *if* you know what you need to re-enable after you have done it.

If it is not your personally owned device then you should be giving it to your local IT support to fix.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! I believe I understand now. I wont do that...

Comment: @SarahSchnoor what I've mentioned is worst case and it could be that resetting it may do nothing but you do not know if your IT people have set up something special. If it is your home system though and you know for a fact that you do not have an "exotic" setup then you could well be fine. The key thing is to know *why* you are resetting the bios configuration and what things you need to set back up.